# How to copy macro from xlsm file and insert it into another xlsm file?

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlwings

I am trying to copy macro from a xlsm file and paste it in a new xlsm file.I am researching in win32com and xlwings but did not find anything useful. A hint to solve the problem is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Install Python 2.7 (Could not get it to work on Python 3)
- Install Xlsxwriter: `pip install XlsxWriter`
- Run the Part 1 code below where you keep your xlsm file to extract the VBA code (Replace xlsm_file variable with your macro file name)
- Run the Part 2 code below to insert the vba in your new workbook.

```
#Part 1:
#!C:\Python27\python.exe

##############################################################################
#
# vba_extract - A simple utility to extract a vbaProject.bin binary from an
# Excel 2007+ xlsm file for insertion into an XlsxWriter file.
#
# Copyright 2013-2019, John McNamara, jmcnamara@cpan.org
#
import sys
from zipfile import ZipFile
from zipfile import BadZipfile

# The VBA project file we want to extract.
vba_filename = 'vbaProject.bin'

# Get the xlsm file name from the commandline.
xlsm_file = 'Macro_file1.xlsm'

try:
    # Open the Excel xlsm file as a zip file.
    xlsm_zip = ZipFile(xlsm_file, 'r')

    # Read the xl/vbaProject.bin file.
    vba_data = xlsm_zip.read('xl/' + vba_filename)

    # Write the vba data to a local file.
    vba_file = open(vba_filename, "wb")
    vba_file.write(vba_data)
    vba_file.close()

except IOError as e:
    print("File error: %s" % str(e))
    exit()

except KeyError as e:
    # Usually when there isn't a xl/vbaProject.bin member in the file.
    print("File error: %s" % str(e))
    print("File may not be an Excel xlsm macro file: '%s'" % xlsm_file)
    exit()

except BadZipfile as e:
    # Usually if the file is an xls file and not an xlsm file.
    print("File error: %s: '%s'" % (str(e), xlsm_file))
    print("File may not be an Excel xlsm macro file.")
    exit()

except Exception as e:
    # Catch any other exceptions.
    print("File error: %s" % str(e))
    exit()

print("Extracted: %s" % vba_filename)
```

Run this code to copy the VBA to the new Excel file:

```
#Part 2
import xlsxwriter

# Note the file extension should be .xlsm.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('macros.xlsm')

workbook.add_vba_project('./vbaProject.bin')

workbook.close()
```

Comment: sorry for the delay. Thanks for taking the time. Really appreciate it. :)